How do I reference a form variable from a class function in a watch expression?
A variable on my form is unexpectedly changing during a call to a class function. I want to trace through the class function while watching the form variable but can't directly reference it in a watch expression.
I can, however, reference a form control in a watch expression so I added a text box and timer control. The timer periodically writes the form variable to the text box where I can watch it as I trace through the class function. This seems to work but the form variable doesn't appear to change until the code operation returns from the class function. Is there a better way of debugging this?

Change the variable to a property. Then you can set a breakpoint in the setter and catch it exactly when it is changed.

Alternatively, do not directly manipulate the variable and access it only through a getter function/setter sub and throw a break point on it. @MarkL 's suggestion is going to be simpler however.
